# How do I increment the key in an NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to assign objects to a NSMutableDictionary where the keys of the objects increment but I keep on getting the value 2 assigned as the key. How would I increment the key each time an object is saved to the Dictionary?

Here's my method:

```
 -(void)addToMutableDictionary:(NSString*)value
 {
     //declare variable
     int keyNum = 1;

     keyNum +=1;

     NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt: keyNum];
     int numToInc = [number intValue];
     number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:numToInc];

     //Then I'm adding to the Dictionary:

     [dictionary setObject:value forKey:number];
}
```

my ouput is always:

The number for the key was always 2.

-----> how I got it to work

```
// declare variable outside so that's its incremented and not reset to
// 0 every time the function is executed.
int keyNum = 0;


-(void)addToMutableDictionary:(NSString*)value
{



        keyNum +=1;

        NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt: keyNum];
        int numToInc = [number intValue];
        number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:numToInc];

        //Then I'm adding to the Dictionary:

        [dictionary setObject: object forKey:number];
    }
```

Comment: You always get 2 because you always do 1 + 1. You never reference an object that could already be in the dictionary or the dictionary itself in the process of creating the number. Consider using `[dictionary count]` as the value of `origNumber`.

Comment: `number` *is* 2 when you add the object to the dictionary. Why do you expect a different result?

Comment: I've also tried origNum+=1; though it stays at 2. @Martin R

Comment: Yes, because 1 + 1 = 2. `origNumber` is given the value `1`, then incremented by `1`, giving you `2`.

Comment: Ok my code might be wrong but can you offer a constructive suggestion of how I would increment the key?

Comment: @GerardGrundy: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: With the limited information available, it looks like you should be using an `NSMutableArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing:

```
int origNumber = 1;
origNumber+=1;
```

This makes it so that `origNumber` is always going to be 2, so nothing is actually being incremented. This is why your dictionary will have the key `2` rather than whatever you are expecting.

In another note, even if you were actually incrementing the key, the old key-value pairing would still be there (so your dictionary would have one key-value pair with the key `2` and another with the key `3`, for example) unless you remove the old key-value pair.

Answer (score 3):

I will attempt to help you but I am not sure how successful I will be. Your issue here is that you are always starting your key with the value 1. You then increment that value which ends up being 2. You have attempted to increment it a few different ways but regardless, however you increment it it will always be 1.

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish but I would recommend using two different keys in your dictionary to track the 'object' you want and the 'incrementing key'.

Instead of incrementing the key, increment a value:

```
dictionary[@"number"] = @1;
```

and store the `object` you want:

```
dictionary[@"object"] = object;
```

Then when you want to increment the number just do something like this:

```
dictionary[@"number"] = @([dictionary[@"number"] intValue] + 1);
```

This will then increment your value and it will always move up, not always remaining 2. I hope this makes sense.

Keys are designed to access data. To increment a key seems like a misuse of its purpose (in general). If the key was incremented a few times it would be difficult for you to get the value because you would not know what the new key was, disabling you from accessing your object. This way you can always get the new incremented number because you know its key is "number".

Comment: Hi thank you for helping.  I see what the issue is.  I need to have a int and adding to the Dictionary to be in a loop for the key to increment. I'm incrementing the key to keep track of the object I'm adding to the NSDictionary.

Comment: There is an error with this statement:

Comment: There is an error with this statement: [dictionary setObject@([dictionary[@"number"] intValue]+1) forKey@"number"]; Should it be:  [dictionary setObject:@([dictionary[@"number"] intValue]+1) forKey:@"number"];  it's missing some : after setObject and forKey

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you want is a simple code, but it seems like you are making it complicated. I assumes your requirement is to store some `object`(I dont know whether its same obj or different) into a dictionary with different keys. If my assumption is correct, then you can simply do like this:

```
for(int index=1; index<100; index++){
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:index];         
    [dictionary setObject: object forKey:number];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int origNumber =0;


-(void)methodToIncrementKey
{
    origNumber+=1;
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:origNumber];
    int numToInc = [number intValue];
    number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:numToInc];

    //Then I'm adding to the Dictionary:

    [dictionary setObject: object forKey:number];
}
```

I had to put the key variable outside of the function.